# Concatena em vez de somar

Tags: javascript

Bom, eu preciso que a variável "_som" retorne uma soma, em vez de concatenar

```
_eb.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if (_mon > d.v_eleitor){
        var md = _mon - d.v_eleitor;
        k.innerHTML="$"+md+",00";
        _mon = md;
        _jj.innerHTML = d.x_eleitor;
        if (_pp == ""){
            _pp.setAttribute("value", d.x_eleitor);
        } else {
            var yy = _pp.getAttribute("value");
            var _som = eval("yy + 15");
            alert(_som);
            _pp.setAttribute("value", _som);
        }
    } else {
        alert(d._eleitor);
    }
});
```

preciso que ela retorne a soma no atributo "value" desta barra de progresso:

```
<progress id="progress_bar" value="" max="1000">
```

Comment: Testa com `var _som = parseInt(yy, 10) + 15;`. Se fôr o caso de teres valores com parte decimal testa com `parseFloat`...

Comment: Explica melhor o que o código faz e monta um exemplo com o jsFiddle. Assim a pergunta fica mais clara e é mais fácil ajudar-te.

Comment: @renan Ele veio do [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)... ;)

Comment: é simples, não precisa saber o que as variáveis fazem, só preciso que some ao invés de concatenar

Comment: @ariel para o que você perguntou, o comentário do Sergio já responde.

Comment: Esta também é uma opção
var yy = +_pp.getAttribute("value"); 
var _som = yy + 15;

Answer (score 2):

O Sérgio já lhe deu uma possível resposta para a sua questão. Provavelmente o seu `value` está sendo lido como `String` e, portanto, não pode ser somado a um `inteiro` sem ser convertido primeiro.

Altere a linha:

```
var _som = eval("yy + 15");
```

Para:

```
var _som = parseInt(yy, 10) + 15;
```

Outra maneira é tirar as aspas, e colocar um `+` antes do `yy`:

```
var _som = eval(+yy + 15);
```